# change spinner promt on spinner selection

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner with three options ("one", "two" "three"). When user selects "One" the spinner prompt changes to "One". When user picks "Three" a `DatePickerDialog` starts and based on user input i want to change the prompt to a custom message.**At the same time** I want the spinner to keep the values "one", "two" "three".

Is there a way to do that?

Here is what I've done so far,

**MainActivity**

```
    spinner=(MySpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    SpinnerAdapter sa=new SpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"});
    spinner.setAdapter(sa);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

**The listener**

```
 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: var = 0; break;
                case 1: var = 1; break;
                case 2: var = 3; 

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(this, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "fg");break;
                }

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, new FRTransactions()).commit();                          
    }
```

**SpinnerAdapter**

```
public class MySpinner extends Spinner {

int previousPos=-1;

public MySpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    super.setSelection(position);

    if (position==getSelectedItemPosition()&&previousPos==position){
        getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(null, null, position, 0);
    }
    previousPos=position;
}


class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Android.widget.SpinnerAdapter {

Context context;
TextView tv;
String[] strings;

public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context=context;
    this.strings=objects;
}


@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    return makeLayout(position, convertView, parent, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

    int pos=position;

    if (parent instanceof AdapterView)
        pos = ((AdapterView) parent).getSelectedItemPosition();

    return makeLayout(pos, convertView, parent, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
}

private View makeLayout(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent, final int layout){

    if (convertView!=null) tv=(TextView)convertView;
    else tv=(TextView)LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);

tv.setText(strings[position]);

    return tv;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return strings.length;
}
}
```

Comment: Use spinner.setPrompt("New prompt message");

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, what about [`setPrompt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setPrompt(java.lang.CharSequence)) method?

You can use it in your `onItemSelected()` method.

Comment: Well, i've tried that but for some reason setPrompt() is not firing.

Comment: Put it into a handler then
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
 spinner.setPrompt("New prompt message");
 }
 }, 200);

Comment: Well, that doesn't work either.I think it has to do with spinnerMode.With dialog setPrompt() works fine, with dropdown it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        spinner.setPrompt("New prompt message");
    }
}, 200);
```